# Android gridview : Trying to reproduce interface + lags

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I have 2 problems :

- I am trying to reproduce an interface (see below)
- My gridview lag so much

I would like to reproduce this interface : Each item has a random height of ImageView.

[image]

Today here is my result :

[image]

What is best way to create gridview like that ?

Here is the code of my adapter :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class AllAnnonces_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Annonce> {

    Typeface robotolight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    Typeface robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

    ArrayList<Integer>  lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public AllAnnonces_custom_adapter(Activity activity, List<Annonce> annonces) {
        super(activity, 0, annonces);
        lista.add(120);
        lista.add(170);
        lista.add(220);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView;
        Annonce annonce = getItem(position);

        //rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_annonces_item, null);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// IMAGE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //ImageView imageAnnonce = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_image) ;
        ImageView imageAnnonce = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image) ;

        Random r = new Random();
        imageAnnonce.getLayoutParams().height = lista.get(r.nextInt(lista.size()));

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
        .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .build();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config); 
        imageLoader.displayImage(annonce.getImage(), imageAnnonce);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// TITLE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //TextView titre = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_titre); 
        TextView titre = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);   
        titre.setText(annonce.getTitle());
        titre.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// VILLE OBJET
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //TextView villeObj = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_ville);
        TextView villeObj = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_ville);
        villeObj.setText(annonce.getVilleObjet());
        villeObj.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// PRIX
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //TextView prix = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.allannonces_prix);   
        TextView prix = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_prix);    
        prix.setText("€" + annonce.getPrix() + ",00 EUR");
        prix.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

        return rowView;

    }




}
```

[UPDATE]

New code of adapter after remarks :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class AllAnnonces_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Annonce> {

    Typeface robotolight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    Typeface robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

    public AllAnnonces_custom_adapter(Activity activity, List<Annonce> annonces) {
        super(activity, 0, annonces);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView==null) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.imageAnnonce = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image) ;
            viewHolder.titre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            viewHolder.villeObj = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_ville);
            viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_prix);  

            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Annonce annonce = getItem(position);

        if (annonce != null) {

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config); 
            imageLoader.displayImage(annonce.getImage(), viewHolder.imageAnnonce);

            viewHolder.titre.setText(annonce.getTitle());
            viewHolder.titre.setText(annonce.getTitle());
            viewHolder.titre.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.villeObj.setText(annonce.getVilleObjet());
            viewHolder.villeObj.setText(annonce.getVilleObjet());
            viewHolder.villeObj.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

            viewHolder.prix.setText(annonce.getPrix());
            viewHolder.prix.setText("€" + annonce.getPrix() + ",00 EUR");
            viewHolder.prix.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        ImageView imageAnnonce;
        TextView titre;
        TextView villeObj;
        TextView prix;
    }


}
```

Comment: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Comment: it lags because you're not using the `ViewHolder` pattern and because you're doing the Image handler/download initialization every time. I'm sure you can do it just once.

Comment: @PratikButani Thanks for the link. I have updated my code with this library. But i get images with big height ! How can i reproduce pinterest look ?

Comment: @Budius Thanks. I use ViewHolder pattern now. See my updated post. Now i would like to have the look of pinterest app. And now i get image with enormous height..